# how to delete all entries ldap java

Tags: java, spring, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

I have an application in Java, using Spring LDAP and Java Naming. The problem is when I delete a branch that contains entries. example:

```
root
|
|----A
|    |
|    |--A1
|       |
|       |----A2
|            |
|            |---A3  
|
|
|-----B
```

When I try to delete the branch A, sends me the following exception:

```
[LDAP: error code 66 - subordinate objects must be deleted first]
```

Please help me! thank you!

Greetings.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Spring LDAP, you should be able to accomplish this using LdapTemplate#unbind method that takes 'recursive' argument:

[http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html#unbind(javax.naming.Name](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html#unbind%28javax.naming.Name), boolean)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the LDAP server supports the TreeDelete extended operation or request control, whatever it is, and you can find a Java implementation of the client side code, you will have to traverse the subtree and delete the entries bottom-up.