# How can I delete an entity in LDAP recursively

Tags: recursion, ldap, subscriber, ldif

I have the following tree in LDAP

```
Legend
$Msisdn = 13217654321   // 11 digits phone number: (contry)+(area)+(number) 
$Imsi   = 999888000007777   // standard 15 digits IMSI number
$MobileDomain = ims.mnc888.mcc999.3gppnetwork.org

+ HssNodeName
| + HSS
| | + HSS-Subscribers
| | | + HSS-Subscriber (HSS-SubscriberID=$Msisdn@$MobileDomain)
| | | | + HSS-User (HSS-PrivateUserId=$Imsi)
| | | |   + HSS-Msisdn (HSS-Msisdn=$Msisdn)
| | | | + HSS-SubscriberServiceProfile
| | | | + HSS-PublicIdentificationData (sip:$Imsi@$MobileDomain)
| | | | + HSS-PublicIdentificationData (sip:\+$Msisdn@$MobileDomain)
| | | | + HSS-PublicIdentificationData (tel:\+$Msisdn)
```

I need to delete HSS-Subscriber and all the entities under it. I have LDIF files with the following commands (each LDIF file contains 1 command):

```
** PublicIdentificationDataTel.ldif **
dn: HSS-PublicIdValue=tel:\+$Msisdn,
    HSS-SubscriberID=$Msisdn@$MobileDomain,
    HSS-SubscriberContainerName=HSS-Subscribers,
    applicationName=HSS,nodeName=HssNodeName
changeType: delete

** PublicIdentificationDataSip2.ldif **
dn: HSS-PublicIdValue=sip:\+$Msisdn@$MobileDomain,
    HSS-SubscriberID=$Msisdn@$MobileDomain,
    HSS-SubscriberContainerName=HSS-Subscribers,
    applicationName=HSS,nodeName=HssNodeName
changeType: delete

** PublicIdentificationDataSip1.ldif **
dn: HSS-PublicIdValue=sip:$Imsi@$MobileDomain, 
    HSS-SubscriberID=$Msisdn@$MobileDomain,
    HSS-SubscriberContainerName=HSS-Subscribers,
    applicationName=HSS,nodeName=HssNodeName

** SubscriberServiceProfile.ldif **
dn: HSS-SubscriberServiceProfileId=SubServProf$Msisdn,
    HSS-SubscriberID= $Msisdn@$MobileDomain,
    HSS-SubscriberContainerName=HSS-Subscribers,
    applicationName=HSS,nodeName=HssNodeName
changetype: delete

** MsIsdn.ldif **
dn: HSS-Msisdn=$Msisdn,
    HSS-PrivateUserID=$Imsi@$MobileDomain,
    HSS-SubscriberID=$Msisdn@$MobileDomain,
    HSS-SubscriberContainerName=HSS-Subscribers,
    applicationName=HSS,nodeName=HssNodeName
changeType: delete

** HssUser.ldif **
dn: HSS-PrivateUserID=$Imsi,
    HSS-SubscriberId=$Msisdn@$MobileDomain, 
    HSS-SubscriberContainerName=HSS-Subscribers,
    applicationName=HSS,nodeName=HssNodeName
changeType: delete

** HssSubscriber.ldif **
dn: HSS-SubscriberId=$Msisdn@$MobileDomain,
    HSS-SubscriberContainerName=HSS-Subscribers,
    applicationName=HSS,nodeName=$NODENAME
changeType: delete
```

Running the above LDIF files in the order I wrote them works properly, but sending 8 delete commands for 1 object I want to delete... it is not very elegant. I am looking for a better and more elegant way to do this. I know that I cannot delete an entry that has entries under it, but I am hoping to find a way to make my delete process shorter and more elegant.

I saw the questions [how to delete all entries ldap java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002206/how-to-delete-all-entries-ldap-java), the solution there does not apply to my problem as it involves `Spring framework` which we do not use. There's a plan to integrate `Spring framework` in our project, but it will be **AFTER** we need to deliver this for our customer.

Is there are a way to recursively delete an entity from the tree? for example, I will send the DN of the object (top of the tree) that I want to delete and somehow LDAP will automatically delete it and all the entries under it.

I am currently looking at `ldapdelete` switches to see if any of them can help me with this.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: You can use the Delete Subtree control, if your LDAP Server supports it.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that one. I send a question to our customer's engineering team. Also, I don't have "Subtree" control. I am sending an LDIF, it's run on the customer's LDAP server and I get a Confirm-Reject response. I am using JXplorer client to view the data on our customer's server.

Comment: `ldapdelete` should have it in the options. It's a piece of magic you put into the request, but it requires presence of an optional overlay in the case of the OpenLDAP server for example.

Comment: It's irrelevant, I got an answer from our customer - the LDAP server doesn't support the TreeDelete extended operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no solution for this because the LDAP server doesn't support the TreeDelete extended operation.